# Are all diffuse measures 0-1 on the tail sigma-field?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

More specifically: let $\Omega$ be the set of infinite binary strings, and $\mathcal{F}$ the Borel algebra. Let $X_n$ be the map that projects each string to its n-th coordinate. Let $\mathcal{G}_n=\sigma\{X_m: m\geq n\}$. The tail sigma-field in this case is given by $\mathcal{T}=\bigcap_n\mathcal{G}_n$. I understand that Kolmogorov's 0-1 law says, if $X_i$'s are independent according to $P$ (so $P$ is some measure for infinite iid coin flips), then $P$ is 0-1 on $\mathcal{T}$. I am curious if there is any extension of this result to other diffuse measures. In particular, suppose $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}$ that satisfies $\mu\{x\}=0$ for all $x$. Is it necessary that $\mu$ be 0-1 on $\mathcal{T}$? (My hunch says no, but I am having a hard time coming up with a counterexample, partly because I don't know any specific construction of diffuse measures on this space other than taking convex combinations of the coin measures...) Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, and your convex combination idea already works.  Let $P_1$ be the measure where the coins are independent and each comes up heads with probability $1/2$.  Let $P_2$ be similar but the coins come up heads with probability $2/3$.  Both measures are diffuse.  If $A$ is the tail event that half of the flips, on average, are heads (i.e. $A=\{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} (X_1 + \dots + X_n) = \frac{1}{2}\}$), then you know from the strong law of large numbers that $P_1(A) = 1$ and $P_2(A)=0$.  Let $Q = \frac{1}{2} P_1 + \frac{1}{2} P_2$.  Then $Q$ is also diffuse and $Q(A) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: ah thanks so much! for some reason I got myself into the weird assumption that all coin measures agree on the tail sigma-algebra, which is obviously wrong.